# Png image changes color when put on artboard

Tags: sketch-app

1. Opened a new blank sketch project
2. Drag a png file from finder on the canvas
3. The png image is imported correctly and colors of it are correct
4. Draw an artboard arround this imported image, placing it inside the artboard=> colors of the image change (they are considerable lighter as if brightness boosted)

What is going on here?

Comment: can you share your png

Comment: Are you sure that the solid colors of the .png have 100% opacity? Sometimes the workspace is light grey and the artboard is white which would explain why it's looking brighter.

Comment: edit the post, to include the sketch file. Thank you for the feedback so far guys. I really don't understand what is happening here...

Comment: @zholdas updated post to include the sketch that has the png imported already, it shows clearly color difference, thanks for your feedback so far

Comment: It seems than your png already has some transparency (70%-80%).
So when you importing it to Sketch and place to artboard it becomes lighter.

Comment: Hmm will check that I really believed it was opaque

Comment: @zholdas turned out the PNG's ware ok. See the answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out nothing todo with the png file but a real bug in sketchapp. I was in contact with their support department and they offered me the solution that I can confirm indeed works:

> I think I can figure out whats going on there. We’re aware of an issue
>   that is related to Default Style. If you have a Default Style defined
>   with an opacity of 50%, this opacity is applied to new Artboards too.
>   So the workaround for this is to define a new Default Style from a
>   Shape without opacity applied.
>
> We’re working to solve that. Apologies!